# nginx php5-fpm conf file missing in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

My php5-fpm conf on nginx works correctly . But yesterday, it didn't work.
After giving php5-fpm -t command , I get following error:

```
[05-Jul-2016 08:59:32] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
[05-Jul-2016 08:59:32] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
[05-Jul-2016 08:59:32] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

After giving ls command on /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d and /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d, there is no file.

My Nginx conf:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name localhost;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/html;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with `php5-fpm`, not `nginx`.

Ultimately, your config files seem to have disappeared. Your best bet is to reinstall `php5-fpm`, purging the old config files, and replacing them.

On Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-fpm
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```